# Dependent Task and Pull request

Tags: git, azure-devops

I have following scenario.

- Three Tasks depends on one another.
- Now workflow for Git (VSTS) with visual studio has following things. ( Means it is decided by our team)

  - Before start working on any Task . Please create Branch of it then work. Create Pull request.
  - Now Pull request still is in pending state for approval. Developer want to start working on Task 2 which is depends on Task 1 how he create branch. As he need code that is present in Task 1 Branch and it is still not merged with main branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The branch for task2 should be created from the branch for task1**, even though the branch for task1 has not been merged into `master` branch.

And after the PR completing, there usually has two ways to merge the branch for task2 into master branch: **create a PR to merge branch for task2 directly**; **rebase the branch for task2 onto master branch and then create a PR**.

Let's illustrate both ways by graphs. Assume `feature1` is the branch for task1, and `feature2` is the branch for task2. The commit history as below:

```
...---A---B---C  master
           \
            D---F---G   feature1
```

Since task2 is depend on the task1, so you should create `feature2` branch from `feature1` branch. Then develop and commit changes on `feature2` branch. The commit history will be:

```
...---A---B---C  master
           \
            D---F---G   feature1
                     \
                      H---I  feature2
```

And when the PR has complete to merge `feature1` branch into `master` branch, the commit history will be (commit `M` is the merge commit):

```
...---A---B---C-------M  master
           \         /
            D---F---G   feature1
                     \
                      H---I  feature2
```

For creating another PR to merge `feature2` branch into `master` branch, there usually has two ways as below:

#### Option 1: create a PR to merge feature2 branch into master branch directly

When the work on task2 (`feature2` branch) is finihed, you can create another PR to merge `feature2` into `master` branch directly.

And after the PR completing, the commit history will be:

```
...---A---B---C-------M-------N  master
           \         /       /
            D---F---G---H---I   feature2
                    |
                 feature1
```

#### Option 2: rebase feature2 branch onto master branch and then create a PR

Since `master` branch has already contains the changes for task1 (`feature1` branch), you can rebase `feature2` branch onto `master` branch by below command:

```
git rebase --onto master feature1 feature2
```

Then the commit history will be:

```
                        H'---I'  feature2
                       /
...---A---B---C-------M  master
           \         /
            D---F---G   feature1
```

And then you can create a PR to merge `feature2` branch into `master` branch. After the PR completing, the commit history will be:

```
                        H'---I'  feature2
                       /      \
...---A---B---C-------M--------N  master
           \         /
            D---F---G   feature1
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this should not be happening if you design your Git workflows/sprints properly.  If you do see this happen often, then I think you should view it as a workflow problem.

If you must deal with this, then one option you could try would be to rebase the task 2 branch on the task 1 branch.  That is, treat the task 2 branch as being a spur from task 1, and not from master.  Here is some Git code you might try:

```
# from task1
git checkout -b task2
# work work work ... complete the task
git rebase task1
# then end task2 by merging into task1, not master
git checkout task1
git merge task2
```

You might use a variation of the above as well.  The basic idea behind my suggestion is to make task 1 the new destination branch for task 2.